# C - Pointers, functions and recursion

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, linked-list

Just trying to get some code to work involving pointers, functions and recursion:

```
Node * root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
root->data = "1";
root->next = NULL;
root->child = NULL;

Node * G = NULL;
BuildGraph(root, &G);
printf("Root is: %d\n", root->data);
Print(G, ">>"); // Custom Print function
```

And BuildGraph:

```
void BuildGraph(Node * head, Node ** G) {
    if (head->child == NULL) { // No child
        printf("Head has no child! %d\n", head->data);
        Push(head, &G);
        Print(G, ">>");
        return;
    }
    BuildGraph(head->child, &G);
    return;
}
```

And so when I run the program, my output goes like this:

```
Head has no child! 1 // printf in BuildGraph
G: 1>> // Print(G, ">>") in BuildGraph
Root is: 1
G is empty! // Print(G, ">>") in main
```

Anyone know the reason G is not carrying over into main?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Within `void BuildGraph()`, `BuildGraph(head->child, &G);` should be `BuildGraph(head->child, G);`.  No `&`, Likely the same with `Push(head, &G);`

Within your build function, G is a `Node **`.  Outside in main(), G is a `Node *`.

Consider using a different and more expansive variable name than G within `BuildGraph()`.  Maybe something like

```
void BuildGraph(Node * head, Node ** AddressG) {
    if (head->child == NULL) { // No child
        printf("Head has no child! %d\n", head->data);
        Push(head, AddressG);
        Print(AddressG, ">>");
        return;
    }
    BuildGraph(head->child, AddressG);
    return;
}
```

I am confident that you compilation provided warning messages concerning this issue.  If they did not recommend investigating how to turn them on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed all the `&` characters like you said and still the list yields empty after calling `BuildGraph`. What I'm trying to achieve is a recursive way to populate `G` using the `child` and `next` structures starting from some node `head`. I've implemented Push/Pop using `Node ** somelist` without having to return the new list which is nice, and I'm looking for a way to do that here. Any more ideas?

Comment: Likely need to see 1) more of your code, 2) input data 3) compiler warning messages.  That may need to be a re-vamped question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No compiler warning messages when I run it, and input data is root node. As for more code, there shouldn't be any need for it. The original post has outlined the problem. The output for `G` in the last line should be `G: 1>>` (in main) as it is in the `BuildGraph` loop, but instead it is giving me `G is empty!`.

Comment: I don't see where "is empty!" comes from.  You _must_ be getting warnings as `root->data = "1";` implies data is `char *` yet `printf("Head has no child! %d\n", head->data)` implies data is `int`.  Or your warnings are not turned on.

Comment: Don't worry about the Print function, that's a simple custom one that works fine.. The real problem is that G is NOT being updated in main when `BuildGraph` pushes to it.

Comment: Suggest posting `Push()` here or in a new post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've found the solution after playing around with it a little more. In main I have `Node * G` and pass in `&G` to `BuildGraph` for `Node ** G`, but then in `BuildGraph` I was Pushing/Recursing with `&G` instead of the real pointer, `&(*G)`. Replacing that with each instance of `&G` fixed my issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Travv92 certainly your compiler must be giving warnings about such or you have disabled warnings.   Recommend solving that issue.  TTFN